# Gnuplot: Aligning several graphs

Tags: gnuplot

I have two time-domain signals. Now I want to plot the range 10..20 seconds from signal 1 and the range 12...22 seconds from signal 2 in a single plot. However, I tried it this way, which fails:

```
plot [10:20] 'signal1.txt' using 1:2 with line lt -1 lw 1 fc rgb "black" title 'Signal 1',\
 [12:22] 'signal2.txt' using 1:2 with line lt -1 lw 1 fc rgb "black" title 'Signal 2'
```

gnuplot says "invalid expression" for to the second range definition ([12:22]).

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the way in which it fails? Could you show a representative sample of your data?

Comment: gnuplot says "invalid expression" for to the second range definition ([12:22]).

Comment: Do you need to specify the range of each axis exactly, or would you be happy with gnuplot calculating the range for you?  You can do the latter with `ytics autofreq` and `y2tics autofreq`.

Answer (score 1):

If one tries

```
plot [3:6] sin(x), [-2:8] cos(x)
```

it's easy to realize that the only interval that counts is the first one.

To achieve his/her intent the OP may recur to an external program or use something similar to

```
set xrange [-10:10]
plot x<3?1/0:x<=6?sin(x):1/0, x<-2?1/0:x<=8?cos(x):1/0
```

The external program could simply be a shell script that leverages on `awk` to filter *not interesting* abscissae.

[image]

It's relatively easy to map my proposal to OP requirements

```
plot 's1' using 1:($1<10?1/0:$1<=20?$2:1/0) w l, 's2' using 1:($1<14?1/0:$1<=22?$2:1/0) w
```